# How Can I capture the raw text of an entire RabbitMQ message including the headers

Tags: structure, rabbitmq, message

I have a small Java application that publishes and subscribes based on the routing tutorial on rabbitMQ. I have the rabbitMQ broker software installed on a linux machine with the web utility enabled.

Is there any chance I can either view an entire message in its raw text form with the headers,  in a similar way that you can capture a HTTP request by using fiddler? Is there a method in the RabbitMQ java libraries that allows you to get this as a string, or can fiddler be tinkered with in order to catch a message.

I have tried googling and sifting through manuals

Max

Comment: You can use wireshark for that, but for debug reason I prefer to publish message to queue and then view it from RabbitMQ admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct! Wireshark lets you capture a AMQP packet and you can see the message header and body. You can even see the raw hexidecimal.

Thanks alot

Comment: Please give me any reference for this.

Comment: you want instructions on how to use wireshark to capture the AMQP packet sent by rabbitMQ?